# Show coordinates in other projections (ArcGIS Javascript API)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinates

Is it possible to change this sample that it will be show x,y coordinates in **wkid:5514** ?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Create Map Display Mouse Coordinates</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">

<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>
<script> 
  var map;
  require([
    "esri/map", "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils", "dojo/dom", 
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(
    Map, webMercatorUtils, dom
  ) {
    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "streets",
      center: [-47.109, 14.945],
      zoom: 2
    });
    map.on("load", function() {
      //after map loads, connect to listen to mouse move & drag events
      map.on("mouse-move", showCoordinates);
      map.on("mouse-drag", showCoordinates);
    });

    function showCoordinates(evt) {
      //the map is in web mercator but display coordinates in geographic (lat, long)
      var mp = webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint);
      //display mouse coordinates
      dom.byId("info").innerHTML = mp.x.toFixed(3) + ", " + mp.y.toFixed(3);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Geometry service project method](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#project) to do this projection. Since it is an asynchronous call, it will not be as responsive as the example (which is being calculated in the browser). The core code to change is in `showCoordinates`:

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/f8e62ajc

*Edit:* John Gravois has a [blog post](https://geonet.esri.com/groups/geodev/blog/2014/11/03/use-proj4js-alongside-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript-to-reproject-coordinates-on-the-fly) explaining this exact problem and solution of doing the reproject in the browser using Proj4JS. This is a better solution since it will be fast and responsive because it is in doing everything in the browser.

Comment: I wrote a blog about integrating proj4js to do clientside reprojection as well: https://geonet.esri.com/groups/geodev/blog/2014/11/03/use-proj4js-alongside-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript-to-reproject-coordinates-on-the-fly